# Using pandas df.apply with a function that returns a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a JSON file from which I'm initially reading into a pandas DF. It looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  ...
"Info": [
            {
                "Type": "A",
                "Desc": "4848",
                ...
            },
            {
                "Type": "P",
                "Desc": "3763",
                ...
            },
            {
                "Type": "S",
                "Desc": "AUBERT",
                ...
            }
        ],
...
}
```

I have a function that will loop over the "Info" field and depending on "Type" will store information into a dictionary and return that dictionary. Then I want to create new columns in my df based on the values stored in the dictionary using `df.apply`. Please see below:

```
def extract_info(self):
    def extract_data(df):
        dic = {'a': None, 'p': None, 's': None}
        for info in df['Info']:

            if info['Type'] == "A":
                dic['a'] = info['Desc']
            if info['Type'] == "P":
                dic['p'] = info['Desc']
            if info['Type'] == "S":
                dic['s'] = info['Desc']
        return dic

self.df['A'] = self.df.apply(extract_data, axis=1)['a']
self.df['P'] = self.df.apply(extract_data, axis=1)['p']
self.df['S'] = self.df.apply(extract_data, axis=1)['s']

return self
```

I have also tried doing:

```
self.df['A'] = self.df.apply(lambda x: extract_data(x['a']), axis=1)
```

But these are not working for me. I have looked at other SO posts about using `df.apply` with function that returns dictionary but did not find what I need for my case. Please help.

I could write 3 separate functions like `extract_A`, `extract_B` and `extract_C` and return single values each to make `df.apply` work but that means running the for loop 3 times, one for each function. Any other suggestions other than use of a dictionary is welcome too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing it in a dictionary, I can store them as variables and return them in my `extract_data` function. Then I can assign these values to new columns in my `self.df` directly using `result_type` parameter in `df.apply`.

```
def extract_info(self):
    def extract_data(df):
        a = None
        p = None
        s = None
        for info in df['Info']:
            if info['Type'] == "A":
                a = info['Desc']
            if info['Type'] == "P":
                p = info['Desc']
            if info['Type'] == "S":
                s = info['Desc']

        return a, p, s

self.df[['A', 'P', 'S']] = self.df.apply(extract_data, axis=1, result_type="expand")

return self
```

Output:

```
       A     P       S
0    4848  3763    AUBERT
...
...
```